# New to Drupal and views, how do I change the order of my fields?

Tags: views

How do I change the order of these fields? See the image.
I want to be able to change the output order of these fields.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the View edit page, click the little cog icon in the top-right of the "Fields" pane, there's a rearrange option there.

[image: screenshot of views field rearrange link]

Comment: @JohanDahl If I had a penny for every time I've exclaimed the same thing, I wouldn't be a Drupal developer!